# How to make chromebrowser open in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am running testsuite from jenkins . 
  Test suite successfully build but i am not able to see test case execution with GUI.

can you please help on this .
I had already post the same question 4-5 days back but there's no answer on this question .
So again posting my question and expecting quick response on it.

Comment: Which OS is being used and also where is jenkins installed? local system or remote system and what is operating system for that system?

Comment: I am using windows local machine. Jenkins is installed through window installer and the executable is on C:\program files\jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins service runs as a System user, so you wont be able to see the executions happening.

Follow the below steps:

1. Search for services.msc in windows search and open it as Administrator.
2. search/ find for Jenkins service in the list.
3. Click on Properties and click on Log on tab.
4. Change from Local Account to This Account.
5. For This Account enter the login details of that user.

after this restart the jenkins server and then retrigger the build.